# Repository methods or aggregate root methods?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an entity called `Person`. It represents a person that may share information with other persons. I also define two entities `TelephoneNumber` and `Address`, that represents some information. Each person may provision the database with their telephone number and address, as instances of `TelephoneNumber` and `Address`, and the information provisioned belongs only to that person. Then, a person that owns a certain information telephone number and address may associate these with each other through the entity `Association`, and may share this association to other persons.

I'm trying to follow domain driven design methodology. Since a telephone number or address belongs to only one person, the identities of `TelephoneNumber` and `Address` are local to this `Person`'s identity. So, I think there is an aggregate that includes the entities `Person`, `TelephoneNumber`, `Address` and `Association`. The root of the aggregate would be the entity `Person`. So, obviously I need a repository for the entity `Person`, since it is the aggregate root, and I can "reconstitute" a person element from a data store using this repository.

Now, a certain person wants to add a telephone number and address, and wants to associate them. So, assuming the person already exists in the data store, I get the `Person` in question using the repository. How do I then add the information?

I see two approaches. Using `addTelephoneNumber` and `addAddress` methods in the `Person` entity, or using repositories for `TelephoneNumber`, `Address` and `Association`.

Assuming the first approach is the correct one, what do these methods have to do? How may these methods add information to the data store? I precise that I've chosen a traversal direction for the associations between Person and TelephoneNumber/Address, from TelephoneNumber/Address to Person. So, each time I retrieve a Person, I don't retrieve all its phones and addresses.
In this case, when a person wants to add a phone using the addTelephoneNumber method, what the method does? Where the new phone is put?

**PS**: The telephone numbers and the addresses owned by a person are not necessarily those of this person, they are just information that this person knows and wishes to share with other persons.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand if you make a more accurate example. I am sure that your entities in your real system is not named "X" and "Y"

Comment: @Marius It's done. I thought staying generic would be better, but I think you're right since generally the solutions depend on the domain.

Comment: Do the phone and address you want to add already exist somewhere in the data store or do you want to create them ?

Comment: @ian31 In this scenario, they do not exist since the person wants to provision information. So, I need to instantiate the phone or address using constructor or factory and I need to persist it in the data store.

Comment: Whats the definition of "belongs to"? You say that the phone and address belongs to one person, but may be shared with others. Whats the difference, in terms of legal operations, for a person which owns the information compared to someone who has it through association?

Comment: @Marius Since two persons may know some information about a particular phone, they both need to provision the phone and the associated information. I mean that instances of TelephoneNumber are not shared between persons. If two persons know some information about a particular phone, they both need to create an instance of the TelephoneNumber entity. That's why I use the term "belongs to".

Comment: And the association? Is that between a phonenumbet and an address?

Comment: @Marius Yes, this entity represents an association between a phone and an address. The link between Association and Person is implicit since a person may associate only information it owns.

Comment: Your question is "what do these methods have to do?". That sounds like a question about a specific persistence technology, rather than domain driven design in general. What persistence technology are you using?

Comment: @TomAnderson No, I'm asking without talking about a specific technology.

Comment: As it stands, i don't think there is an entirely technology-neutral answer. The implementation of the repository will be specific to the underlying technology, and the interaction between the domain objects and the repository will be coloured by its implementation.

Comment: For example, if you're using JPA in Java, then all `addTelephoneNumber` needs to do is store a reference to a `TelephoneNumber` object in a field of the `Person`; the JPA implementation will later be able to detect that change, and store the object in the database. But if you're using raw database access, you might need to record the fact that it has changed, or broadcast a change notification to the repository, so it can record the change.

Comment: @TomAnderson I've edited the question. In my case, the Person entity doesn't hold a list of phones and addresses. So, how it works?

Comment: Hmm. You essentially want `Person` to give the impression of containing a list of `Address`es (so that it can have an `addAddress` method), but to not actually contain one, as an implementation detail. The only way to make that work is to have `Person` depend on a repository which can load and store appropriate `Address` objects on demand, but that would be a poor design; the domain objects should not know about the repositories.

Comment: I would suggest rethinking your decision not to include a list of `Address`es in `Person`. That relationship is part of the domain, so it should be part of the object model. I'll write an answer after i get my lunch ...

Comment: @TomAnderson Eric Evans speaks about this possibility in his book. In his example, you have the entities Customer and Cargo. He says "If the Customer has a direct reference to every Cargo it has shipped, it will become cumbersome for long-term, repeat Customers." So, the traversal direction chosen is from Cargo to Customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of an object encapsulating a phone number and an address seems important in your domain, so you could have something like a ContactInfo entity ("Association" seems a bit too vague) containing a PhoneNumber and an Address. Phone and address don't really "change" per se -it's rather the ContactInfo that changes, so you could make them value objects.

Person would remain the aggregate root and the only entity to have a Repository. You'd just call person.AddContactInfo() to add a new contact info and contact infos would be persisted later together with the person.